# Не работает метод Invoke

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < PrisonerPrefab.Length; i++)
        {
            Invoke("_prisoner[i].callRollCall()", UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 5));
        }

    }
}
```

**Из консоли юнити:**

> Trying to Invoke method: PrisonsAI._prisoner[i].callRollCall() couldn't be called.

Comment: По вашему коду невозможно определить причину ошибки. Приведите код всего класса. Первое, что бросается в глаза: `i < PrisonerPrefab.Length`, а затем вы вызываете методы у `_prisoner[i]`, там не должно быть `PrisonerPrefab[i]`?

Comment: Также в Unity желательно избегать метода `Invoke`, ибо он очень сказывается на производительности.

Comment: Да спасибо,я уже все сам решил !!!))

Answer (score 1):

```
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < PrisonerPrefab.Length; i++)
        {
            Invoke("_prisoner[" + i + "].callRollCall()", UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 5));
        }

    }
}
```